Why are my GridDB queries slow even with proper indexing?
I’ve run into a frustrating issue with GridDB where some of my queries are slower than expected, despite having the right indexes in place. The dataset isn’t particularly large, and according to the query execution plan, the indexes are being used. But the performance still isn’t up to par.
Here’s what I’m dealing with:

The slowdowns are happening with both range scans and exact match lookups.

I’ve checked that the GridDB nodes are in good health and not overloaded.

Restarting the GridDB service seems to help temporarily, but the slowness comes back after a while.


Here are some details:
-- Range scan query to fetch data for a specific time period
SELECT 
    sensor_id, 
    AVG(temperature) as avg_temp, 
    AVG(humidity) as avg_humidity
FROM 
    sensor_data 
WHERE 
    timestamp BETWEEN '2024-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2024-08-15 23:59:59' 
    AND location_id = 5
GROUP BY 
    sensor_id
ORDER BY 
    avg_temp DESC;

-- Exact match query to fetch data for a specific sensor at a specific time
SELECT 
    sensor_id, 
    timestamp, 
    temperature, 
    humidity 
FROM 
    sensor_data 
WHERE 
    sensor_id = 'ABC12345' 
    AND timestamp = '2024-08-10 14:30:00';

Index Definitions:
-- Index on the timestamp and location_id columns to optimize range scans
CREATE INDEX idx_timestamp_location ON sensor_data (timestamp, location_id);

-- Index on the sensor_id and timestamp columns to optimize exact lookups
CREATE INDEX idx_sensor_timestamp ON sensor_data (sensor_id, timestamp);

Sample Data:



sensor_id
timestamp
location_id
temperature
humidity




ABC12345
2024-08-01 00:00:00
5
22.5
55


ABC12345
2024-08-01 00:05:00
5
22.7
56


DEF67890
2024-08-01 00:10:00
5
23.1
57


GHI54321
2024-08-01 00:15:00
6
21.9
53


ABC12345
2024-08-10 14:30:00
5
24.3
60



...
The sensor_data table contains time-series data collected from various sensors located in different locations. The queries are intended to retrieve average temperature and humidity over a specific period or to get the exact readings from a particular sensor at a specific time.
Despite having indexes on the columns that are most frequently used in queries (timestamp, location_id, and sensor_id), the query performance is slower than expected.
Specific issues I'm encountering:

The first query that involves range scans across a specific time period is taking much longer than anticipated.

The second query, which should be a straightforward exact match, also shows noticeable delays.


Given this setup, I’m wondering if there’s something I’m missing in terms of GridDB configurations or optimizations that could be causing these intermittent slowdowns. Has anyone else experienced this kind of issue with GridDB, even when indexes are properly set up?
Any advice or insights would be really helpful!

What happens if you change the index to CREATE INDEX idx_timestamp_location ON sensor_data ( location_id, timestamp ); - it makes more sense for location_id to be the first index-columnb because (presumably) it's more selective - then a range-query can be easily done on the leaf-nodes (assuming it's a B-tree, I think?)
